# OpenCV and QT exit code -1073741701

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

After [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32986874/opencv-migration-from-vs2013-to-qt-5-5) question I found that OpenCV gives me this error:

> Starting
>   C:\Users\nikola\Documents\build-ConsoleTry-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MSVC2013_64bit-Debug\debug\ConsoleTry.exe...
>   C:\Users\nikola\Documents\build-ConsoleTry-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MSVC2013_64bit-Debug\debug\ConsoleTry.exe exited with code -1073741701

after trying to run this console code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace::cv;
using namespace::std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    const char* filename = "1-page.png";
   // cout << filename << endl;

    cout << "111" << endl;
    Mat src = imread(filename, 0);
    cout << "222" << endl;
    return a.exec();
}
```

How to fix it? I have copied DLL files in the debug directory. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17909905/5325058) is mentioned the need of conversation of Mat to Qt QImage. Is this the case and are other objects required to be converted?

Result when start .exe from cmd.

[image]

Comment: can you run the .exe from command prompt, and check if other errors are printed? (and NO, you need conversion to QImage only to show image, because you can't use imshow and need to show images with Qt stuff)

Comment: Commenting Mat src.. line works?

Comment: If I comment Mat src line it work with no problem, but I acctualy need to use OpenCV :D. I have added the result from starting it in cmd above.

Comment: (not sure, but) it seems a dll problem. Have you copied them in the correct folder?

Comment: I have copied opencv_core2411.dll and opencv_core2411d.dll from D:\opencv_2411\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin to C:\Users\nikola\Documents\build-ConsoleTry-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MSVC2013_64bit-Debug\debug where is the executable. In Visual Studio 2013 dll problem is fixed with the mentioned above old question with adding the path to the dll to PATH variable in VS 2013, but here in QT I am not shure if it is dll problem.

Comment: if dll folder is already in PATH then it should work... so not a dll probelm :D

Comment: which libraries did you add to your `linker input`? Which library directories did you add to linker? are you compiling 64 bit? please provide your compiler & linker commands or screenshots with all necessary information.

Comment: btw, I think `imread` needs opencv_highgui, not _core

Comment: Micka is right - it do need highgui, so I have copied all .dll files from D:\opencv_2411\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin to debug directory. I was having hadeaches because before this I have copied all .dll files from my Visual Studio 2013 project directory, but they were x86, and the QT project is x64. Thank you, but now I have another problem. In Debug mode the program is starting, then src.empty is true, which mean it cannot load file. If I change to release mode exit code -1073741701 is showned again, which is strange because I load the release .lib files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Micka is right - it do need highgui, so I have copied all .dll files from D:\opencv_2411\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin to debug directory. I was having hadeaches because before this I have copied all .dll files from my Visual Studio 2013 project directory, but they were x86, and the QT project is x64. Thank you all!!! And if someone still have problem see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33016753/opencv-and-qt-imread-exit-code?noredirect=1#comment53858241_33016753) topic too.

Comment: vc12 = Visual Studio 2013.