# OpenCV and QT imread exit code

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, static-libraries, mode

After writting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32990900/opencv-and-qt-exit-code-1073741701) thread I was thinking the problem is solved, but it still is not. In Debug mode the program is starting, then src.empty is true, which mean it cannot load file. If I change to release mode exit code -1073741701 is showned again, which is strange because I load the release .lib files like this:

```
INCLUDEPATH += D:\opencv_2411\opencv\build\include
LIBS += -LD:\opencv_2411\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib \
-lopencv_calib3d2411 \
-lopencv_core2411 \
-lopencv_features2d2411 \
-lopencv_flann2411 \
-lopencv_highgui2411 \
-lopencv_imgproc2411 \
-lopencv_ml2411 \
-lopencv_objdetect2411 \
-lopencv_photo2411 \
-lopencv_stitching2411 \
-lopencv_superres2411 \
-lopencv_ts2411 \
-lopencv_video2411 \
-lopencv_videostab2411
```

Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you copied also release dll in the correct folder? Also try using the full path for the image

Comment: Also, images are for images, you should _write_ the errors into the question

Comment: You probably havent put the image into the realse folder asewll...

Comment: I have tried of course with full path, the image is in release folder. Shame for me I forgot again to copy .dll files to release directory. Now the -1073741701 exit code disappear in release mode, but the other problem is still active, so I have tried to run the program from cmd like in the past topic Miki adviced me and it says that 'Qt5Core.dll is missing from my computer'. Should I download it from internet and why it is missing, I thought it is provided with QT, but the strange think is that it is in D:\QT5\Tools\QtCreator\bin directory where is the executable of qt.

Comment: The error from command line is becase you need to copy also to copy all Qt dll and plugins, or use [windeployqt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html#the-windows-deployment-tool). So keep launching from Qt creator for now. Also, 1) you check if an image is loaded with `if(img.data == NULL){//error}`, 2) try with full path, remember to use double slashes "\\", or "/" in path. 3) don't use `char*`, `std::string` was invented for a reason :D.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot again to copy .dll files to release directory. Now the -1073741701 exit code disappear in release mode. The other problem is solved with the use of full path to the image and the escape of backslash character this way \\, which I forgot again. This was noobie question.